# Android Map Extensions on zoom cluster transition

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer, android-maps-extensions

I was implementig maps extensions in my solution, and i cant figure out how to activate the cluster transition animation. There is a class called ClusterAnimator but is not used in the example.

So the question is, how can activate the cluster transitions in android map extensions implementation using the default clustering strategy?.

I want to get the same transition than the original maps library does on zoom in and out with the markers and clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your clustermanager as the mapview's `OnMapCameraChangeListener` ?

Take a look at the [BigClusteringDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/BigClusteringDemoActivity.java) demo-application, which does the following:

```
getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

**EDIT** I wrongly assumed that the question was about [Google Maps Android API utility library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) and its ClusterManager, which it wasn't.

Comment: I don't think that you are loking at the right library, i'm using Android Extentions Map wich doesn't work whit the native Google maps v2 Cluster Manager. https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions

Comment: You are absolutely right. I can highly recommend Google's utility library though.

Comment: Well, the reason about why i'm using that library is that they extend the Markers object adding a method called "data(Object o)" and "getData()". Basically you can set whatever you want to the marker as info (like a json) and read it after without using hash maps. BTW Did you down vote my question?

Comment: Ok, yes, I had a glimpse at the project and the data property seems indeed useful. And no, I did not down-vote your question.

Comment: Well thanks for trying to help !! :). It's a good library, but poorly documented.